# Date format change in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting, date-formatting

I have a date `12-04-2023 22:30` as a string and need to convert it like `2023-04-11 17:32:38.171728 UTC`
format or vice-versa.  Any help is appreciated.

Tried `parse_datetime` function and `cast` function. Doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First conversion: 12-04-2023 22:30 to 2023-04-11 17:32:38.171728 - Note I noticed the to be converted date is different to input date so considering the format here:

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %R:%E6S",PARSE_DATETIME("%d-%m-%E4Y %H:%M", "12-04-2023 22:30"))  as formated_date
```

Second conversion: this format 2023-04-11 17:32:38.171728 to 12-04-2023 22:30

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M","2023-04-12 22:30:00.000000")   as formated_date
```

Hope this helps